# If-else-statement is working wrong in crontab?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, cron

When i use this:

```
*/5 6-18 * * 1-6 [ "$(ls -A /DIR_WHERE_FILES_ARE_OR_NOT/)" ] &&
  rsync -au /DIR_WHERE_FILES_ARE_OR_NOT/ /DIR_WHERE_FILES_SHOLD_GO; \
  mv /DIR_WHERE_FILES_ARE_OR_NOT/*  /SAVE_DIR/ ||
  mail -s "DIR IS EMPTY" myemail@klkldkl.de <<< "message"
```

i get two mails:

> mv: cannot stat `/DIR_WHERE_FILES_ARE_OR_NOT/*': No such file or
>   directory

and

> "DIR IS EMPTY"

Why?

Comment: What about having a proper script with these conditions and calling it from crontab? Like this it is pretty complicated to trace and maintain.

Comment: Thanks! :) now i have changed the two commands in to { } but it doesnt help

Comment: Only if i ad 
    exit 0;
behind the two commends, i doent get any error mail BUT when files are in the DIR i get a error message: 

/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Answer (score 2):

You get

```
mv: cannot stat `/DIR_WHERE_FILES_ARE_OR_NOT/*': No such file or directory
```

for exactly the reason stated: that directory is empty, hence it does not contain a file named `*` (asterisk). It's just the way glob expansion works in the shell: if the glob doesn't match anything it is passed literally to the command. Since `mv` attemps to rename a non-existing file, it complains as shown.

This would all be much more readable, if instead of a sequence of `&&` and `||` operators in a crontab you would place the whole logic in a script with equivalent `if/else/fi` constructs and just call the script from cron.

You get two mails because you explicitly send the first with `mail -s`. The second is from cron because the output on stderr and stdout is not empty.

Your commands are equivalent to

```
if [ "$(ls ...)" ]; then
   rsync
fi
if ! mv; then
   mail
fi
```

Note that there is no `else`.

Comment: But why crontab do not only the if-statement or the else statement?

Comment: Because of the precedence of `&&` versus `||`.

Comment: To clarify, because of the short-circuiting semantics in conjunction with the semicolon. In shell grammar parlance, the semicolon makes this two separate *AND-OR-lists*. In the second list, `mv || mail`, both are run because the `mv` fails.

Answer (score 2):

Just like user Jens already mentioned, and also from my experience, unless you are using a very simple and usually single command, you should stick to script files. So, in your case, I would go with a script file. I'll give you an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_where_files_are_or_not=/filespath
dir_where_files_should_go=/another/filespath
save_dir=/savefiles/path

# ok, lets start by checking if dir contains files
if [ "$(ls -A $dir_where_files_are_or_not)" ]; then
  # dir contains files, so lets rsync and mv them
  rsync -au $dir_where_files_are_or_not/ $dir_where_files_should_go
  mv $dir_where_files_are_or_not/* $save_dir
else
  # dir is empty, lets send email
   mail -s "DIR IS EMPTY" myemail@klkldkl.de <<< "message"
fi
```

Now, I just put this code in a file. Give it a name, for example "chkfiles" and save it in a directory (I use /usr/local/sbin for all of my scripts).

Next, in a shell, run the command `chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/chkfiles` to make the file executable. Then add the script to your crontab.

I would suggest the following line inside crontab:

```
*/5 6-18 * * 1-6 /bin/bash /usr/local/sbin/chkfiles
```

I used /bin/bash to call the right interpreter for this script. It should now work as expected.

**Important Notes:**

1. Before running the script, you need to change the `dir_where_files_are_or_not`, `dir_where_files_should_go` and `save_dir` vars to your needs.
2. Do **NOT** include trailing slashes in the dirs, otherwise the rsync and mv might not do what you really want

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You get two mails because when `mv` fails, `cron` captures what is written to standard error and mails it to the owner, then runs the `mail` command. You can suppress the error message from `mv` to avoid the mail from `cron`.

```
mv /DIR_WHERE_FILES_ARE_OR_NOT/*  /SAVE_DIR/ 2> /dev/null || mail -s "DIR IS EMPTY" myemail@klkldkl.de <<< "message"
```

Comment: When `mv` fails, `mv` writes to stderr, not `cron`.

Comment: I knew I was wording that poorly, but did not realize just *how* poorly.